# Reason for not able to identify pointer in localhost

Tags: php, database, setting

I am going to retrieve some data from database and display it in php file.

It seems like it can connect to my localhost's database,because code like:

```
<?php foreach($goods as item ):?>
```

haven't occur any errors.

but when it comes to the codes like,

```
<?php echo $item->logo;?>
```

on my browser, it simply display

```
 logo;?>
```

what's wrong with my codes or setting.
As the file is quite big and I think the system config problem(I have reinstalled wampserver), I just show a little bit
my code:

```
<?php echo sizeof($goods);?>
<td class="td_f"><a href="" target="_blank"><IMG src="http://127.0.0.1:8020/UB_real//public/photos/frontimg/<?php echo $item->logo?>"> </a></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: will u post your php code ?

Comment: When you say localhost do you mean you are trying to run this on your PC?

Comment: There are small syntax errors in these snippets. Is this your real code?

Comment: Where you said `<?php foreach($goods as item ):?>` you must say `<?php foreach($goods as $item ); ?>`

Comment: Are you running a webserver on localhost? PHP web pages have to be run through a server, not as local files.

Comment: what do you mean by pointer?

Comment: I am running wampapache on my computer and I put the codes into the designed file
Apache Version : 2.2.8  
PHP Version :5.2.6
MYSQL :5.0.51b

Comment: I think we are going to need to see more of the code to be able to make any sensible suggestions

Comment: Your webserver is showing php pure code as text/html. it's not executing php. check your apache config.

Comment: And also this is completely wrong in php and reason of not showing error is that there is a start for a tag and there is an end. andyour browser recognize it as a HTML tag. <?php foreach($goods as item ):?>
but the second one is closed after $item->. IT IS A HTML TAG : <?php echo $item-> and this is after your tag and is ready to show logo;?>

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code:

Where you said:

```
<?php foreach($goods as item ):?>
```

Must be:

```
<?php foreach($goods as $item ); ?>
```

Note the missing $ before item, and the semicolon ; not the :

If you need to list all the returned values in $goods (for testing purposes), you can always do:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($goods);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: if I cannot do your codes ,does that mean my php is not config  properly ?

Comment: To check if your php is running, just create a file named info.php and paste the code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, save and access to that file. If you see the code, you don't have php properly installed or running. If you see php information, it works.